# Delay after clicking file-upload button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache

When I click on "Select File to Upload" (i.e. input type=file) there is a delay between the time I clicked the button and selected the file to displaying selected file next to the button. Is the browser trying load the file into browser ?? Why is there a delay.

Followup to that, how can I display a "please wait.." message **immediately** after selecting the file. I experimented with various JQ options all seem to be triggering after the initial delay (as I said may be browser is trying to load the file not sure) I want to cover the delay with the loader widget/message.

Please help.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate "delay" ? What is duration of "delay" ?

Comment: Delay is probably 1/4th of a second to 2 seconds or more depending on the size of the file I am trying to select. I tried with multiple machines and looks like standard delay. From the time I select the file to the file name displayed next to "Choose File" (this example is for chrome).  I am OK with delay if it's standard or browser is trying to read that file, but how do I intercept to display the 'Loader' widget before the browser start reading file. All JQ events are happening after the browser red the file.

Comment: You could use `change` event to show "Loader" widget, then remove widget once `FileList` object is defined within `change` handler. What is the content-length of the file ?

Comment: I am using files around 500K to 2M to test. I tried $("input[type=file]").change(function(){ and it triggers after the delay. The only thing that remotely does what I need is by using $("#logox").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("input[type=file]").trigger("click");   
  }); and passing the control to change,

Comment: The issue with above is if I use $.mobile.loader('show') just before the trigger and if the user cancels the upload file selector (windows window) then I have no way to cancel it. Either way I am curious what's happening with browser

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets ,  jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: You could try using `.focus()` on a `button` element , then trigger `change` event from `button`

Comment: OK - I will get that added as soon as I am home to create an account. But literally the code is <form><input name="logo" id="logo" type="file" /></form> that's all no JS etc. to demostrate the delay.

Comment: See post; approach uses `button` element ,  `.click()` , `.one()` , `.focus()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach is to use `button` to element to trigger `click` on `input type="file"` sibling to `Open File` dialog; append "Loading" widget to document; utilize `.one()` to attach `focus` event to `$(window)` to remove "Loading" widget when `window` regains `focus` following user selection of file or closing of `Open File` dialog.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var spinner = $("<img />", {
    "id": "spinner",
    "src": "data:image/gif;charset=binary;base64,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"
});
  $(this).after(spinner).nextAll("input:first").click();
  $(window).one("focus", function() {
    $("#spinner").detach()
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>choose file</button>
<input type="file" style="opacity:0;"/>
```

Comment: This gets close (PS: Thank you very much for spending your valuable time to respond, I really appreciate it). In the code snippet 1) User selects choose file 2) spinner starts 3) user selects a file 4) spinner stops 5) delay happens 5) file ready for upload.  Spinner is stopping at step #4 not after step #5. Any case this solution did address the issue of how to stop if the user did not select a file.

Comment: May be there needs to be a conditional statement on detach(), if (file not selected then detach) else detach after the upload etcc.. are complete

Comment: @RaviP Yes, you could use `.detach()` at `change` event for `input type="file"` element. Use condition at `if` for expected result

Comment: Thank you, I could be wrong but the change event is happening after the delay :( I am going to play to see if I can enclose the change event within the window event you suggested.

Comment: This works for the UI, but it doesn't work for actually uploading the file. The problem is that the delay exists in updating the files list of the input element, so when the window receives focus again that list hasn't been updated yet. Listening for the change event doesn't work if the user didn't select anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got to work:
**HTML:**

```
<input class="fileUploadBtn" name="image" type="file"/>
```

**Javascript/ Jquery:**

```
$(".fileUploadBtn").click(function() {
//Your code here to show please wait
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
// Your code here to hide please wait
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined the approach from guest271314 with another method to get the results. I can say I could not have been able to get this far with out his help. on load on image is holding the loader till the image is completely loaded.

The method is

```
enter code here
$('#preview').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $('#preview').find('img')
        .on('load', function() { $.mobile.loading('hide'); });
});
```