# Looping setTimeout stops before it should (creating a spinner)

Tags: javascript, spinner, settimeout

I'm using a setTimeout function that calls itself in a loop in order to create the look of a spinner.  Right now I'm just using a spinner image from Google and rotating the image within a setTimeout function and a global variable for the number of degrees to rotate.  It looks like this:

```
var rotate = 0;
var rotateOn = false;

function rotateSpinner() {
    if (rotateOn) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            rotate +=5
            $('.spinner').css("transform", "rotate(" + rotate + "deg)");
            rotateSpinner();
        }, 30)
    }
}
```

I call the spinner like this, which corresponds with a sending a socket.emit to the server:

```
socket.emit('someEmit', xyz, abc)
rotateOn = true;
rotateSpinner();
$('.spinner').show();
```

And when the response is received from the server, I reverse the code above, which should hide and then stop the spinner.

```
socket.on('someResponse', function() {
    $('.spinner').hide();
    rotateOn = false;
    someOtherFunction();
})
```

I'm using this to fill the gap between the emit to the server and the response in several areas, however, in one of these instances, I have to go through a fairly large number of loops to build the page on the server response and it's causing the spinner to stop for a few seconds before the content actually shows up.  It doesn't seem to matter how I write it out (including moving the statement to turn rotateOn to false to the end, adding a setTimeout function that doesn't turn rotateOn to false until well after the content should be done loading, etc.) - I still get the pause.  Is there anything I can do to counteract this?

Comment: One suggestion, move `$('.spinner').hide();` to `rotateSpinner` and make it `$('.spinner').toggle(rotateOn);`. This will take care of showing and hiding manually at multiple places. Second, instead of having a global variable, make it as a parameter based value. This will help you export it as a utility function and make it generic. Also, try moving `someOtherFunction()` before hiding logic.

Comment: Have you tried using a `.gif` image?

Comment: If not `.gif`, `css transformation` is also a good option. Will save from trouble if manually transforming

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah See http://stackoverflow.com/q/36166084/