# Show loader only after file is selected and hide when cancel or cross button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, loader, jquery-file-upload

I have been trying to show loader when file uploaded using single input element and no other element involved, but its not working.

```html
  <!-- ! ajaxLoader Begin -->
            <div class="ajaxLoader" id="Loader">
                <img src="~/assets/img/loader.gif" alt="">
            </div>
            <!-- ! ajaxLoader End -->

     <input asp-for="File" id="File" type="file" class="form-control DocumentFile" accept=".pdf" title="Browse From Folder" />
```

Below is the javascript:

```js
<script>
$('#File').focus(function (evt) {
 $(this).change(
            function () {
     $('.ajaxLoader').show();
     if ($(this).length === 0) {
     $('.ajaxLoader').hide();
     }
     else{
        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                        url: '@Url.Action("UpdatedDocumentFile", "Document")',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(res) {
      // Do some process on 'res'
      
       $('.ajaxLoader').hide();
     },
                    error: function(e) {
      $('.ajaxLoader').hide();
                    }
                });
    }
   }
  );
    });
 </script>
```

It in anyway ,does not show the loader on file upload. 
Although I tried using below link :
[Loader while file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36166715/5743676)

but it starts loader as soon as the input element is clicked and closes on any actions of File Upload(Upload, Cancel, Cross button click), whereas in my case it calls ajax and do some processing to finally upload file to server.
Also, I have tried with `change event of input file` but it does not work if I open the File Location but cancels on first attempt, it never closes the loader for first trial

How can show/Hide loader in case of File Upload, Cancel  or Cross button click event?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **focusout**, but i would prefer **on click** with a button, but you can also use

**change**

and there is beforesend in ajax, where you can start your loader

```
$('#File').on('change', function (evt) { // or use focusout
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdatedDocumentFile", "Document")',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function ()
        {
            $('.ajaxLoader').show();
        },
        error: function (e) {
            $('.ajaxLoader').hide();
        },
        success: function (res) {
            $('.ajaxLoader').hide();
        }
    });
 });
```

or you can set a defaukt setting for all ajaxs, try this , then you don't need loader in ajax

```
var $loader = $('#Loader'), timer;

 $loader.hide()
.ajaxStart(function()
{
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function()
    {
        $loader.show();
    },
    1000);
})
.ajaxStop(function()
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $loader.hide();
});
```

Comment: loader stays for so short duration plus it starts quite late, almost after 2 secs or more the loader starts and end sooner

Comment: @HinaKhuman check now, you don't need to use loader in ajax, but just define default settings, you need timer, the issue is, ajax load very fast, so the loader appears for very less time,